# How to efficiently remove duplicate collision pairs in spatial hash grid?

Tags: java, performance, geometry, collision-detection

I'm working on a 2D game for android so performance is a real issue and a must. In this game there might occur a lot of collisions between any objects and I don't want to check in bruteforce o(n^2) whether any gameobject collides with another one. In order to reduce the possible amount of collision checks I decided to use spatial hashing as broadphase algorithm becouse it seems quite simple and efficient - dividing the scene on rows and columns and checking collisions between objects residing only in the same grid element.

Here's the basic concept I quickly scratched:

```
public class SpatialHashGridElement
{
    HashSet<GameObject> gameObjects = new HashSet<GameObject>();
}
static final int SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_ROWS = 4;
static final int SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_COLUMNS = 5;
static SpatialHashGridElement[] spatialHashGrid = new SpatialHashGridElement[SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_ROWS * SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_COLUMNS];

void updateGrid()
{
float spatialHashGridElementWidth = screenWidth / SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_COLUMNS;
float spatialHashGridElementHeight = screenHeight / SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_ROWS;
for(SpatialHashGridElement e : spatialHashGrid)
    e.gameObjects.clear();
for(GameObject go : displayList)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < go.vertices.length/3; i++)
    {
        int row = (int) Math.abs(((go.vertices[i*3 + 1] / spatialHashGridElementHeight) % SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_ROWS));
        int col = (int) Math.abs(((go.vertices[i*3 + 0] / spatialHashGridElementWidth) % SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_COLUMNS));
        if(!spatialHashGrid[row * SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_COLUMNS + col].gameObjects.contains(go))
            spatialHashGrid[row * SPATIAL_HASH_GRID_COLUMNS + col].gameObjects.add(go);
    }
}
}
```

The code isn't probably of the highest quality so if you spot anything to improve please don't hesitate to tell me but the most worrying problem that arises currently is that in 2 grid cells there might be same collision pairs checked. Worst case example (assuming none of the objects spans more than 2 cells):

[image]

Here we have 2 gameObjects colliding(red and blue). Each of them resides in 4 cells => therefore in each cell there will be the same pair to check.
I can't come up with some efficient approach to remove the possibility of duplicate pairs without a need to filter the grid after creating it in updateGrid(). Is there some brilliant way to detect that some collision pair has been already inserted even during the updateGrid function? I will be very grateful for any tips!

Comment: did you consider copying sets from your grid or removing collided elements from the grid? Maybe you could provide some measurements? My suggestions seem to be even worse than ignoring it and checking the same collision pairs multiple times...

Comment: the "if gameObjects doesn't contain then add it" is not necessary, because you are using a set.

Comment: Indeed, it's not necessary. Thanks. Regarding the approach with removing collided elements I guess it wouldn't solve my performance requierements. That still would be removing the same pair from each of the cells and I would rather even prevent adding multiple same pairs to different cells in the first place ^^. And I can't ignore it as my precise collision check is a bit intensive and would rather not to do it more than 1 for a given pair : P

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to explain my idea using some pseudo-code (C# language elements):

```
public partial class GameObject {
// ...
   Set<GameObject> collidedSinceLastTick = new HashSet<GameObject>();

   public boolean collidesWith(GameObject other) {
      if (collidedSinceLastTick.contains(other)) {
         return true; // or even false, see below
      }
      boolean collided = false;
      // TODO: your costly logic here

      if (collided) {
         collidedSinceLastTick.add(other);
         // maybe return false if other actions depend on a GameObject just colliding once per tick
      }
      return collided;
   }
// ...
}
```

HashSet and .hashCode() both can be tuned in some cases. Maybe you could even remove `displayList` and "hold" everything in `spatialHashGrid` to reduce the memory foot-print a little bit. Of course do that only if you don't need special access to `displayList` - in XML's DocumentObjectModel objects can be accessed by a path throught the tree, and "hot spots" can be accessed by ID where the ID has to be assigned explicitely. For serializing (saving game state or whatever) it should not be an issue to iterate through `spatialHashGrid` performance-wise (it's a bit slower than serializing the `gameObject` set because you may have to suppress duplicates - using Java serialization it even does not save the same object twice using the default settings, saving just a reference after the first occurence of an object).

Comment: Instead of using a hashset, you can use `Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<GameEntity, Boolean>())`, because you're going to be checking for identity. This makes it so you don't need `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in GameObject.

Comment: @Kyranstar: In the case of big sets `hashCode()` may make sense, however, you are right that in this case just checking identity (sequentially through all elements inside the set) should be faster. I like the idea of "hash buckets" so I use `HashSet`s/`HashMap`s almost everytime (never hit any performance issues).